# How to do pattern program in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, while-loop

I am using Ruby 1.9.3. I have done pattern program like follow:

```
n = 1
while n <= 5
  n.downto 1 do |i|
    print "* "
  end
  puts
  n += 1
end
```

Output of above program is like follow:

```
*
* *
* * * 
* * * *
* * * * *
```

Now I am trying to do pattern program like follow:

```
        *
      * *
    * * *
  * * * *
* * * * *
```

I am not getting idea how can I do it?

Could anyone help me on this?

Thank you.

Comment: before printing the asterisks, print 5-n spaces

Comment: @Pavan - It will throw an exception. Should be `(1..n).each do |i|`

Comment: @BroiSatse Yes! you are right :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `rjust`:

```
n = 1
while n <= 5
  puts "* " * n
  n += 1
end
* 
* * 
* * * 
* * * * 
* * * * * 

n = 1
while n <= 5
  puts ("* " * n).rjust(10)
  n += 1
end
        * 
      * * 
    * * * 
  * * * * 
* * * * *
```

A shortened version of this will be:

```
5.times { |i| puts ('* ' * (i+1)) }
```

and

```
5.times { |i| puts ('* ' * (i+1)).rjust(10) }
```

Comment: The only thing I don't like about `rjust` here is that it is not flexible - if `n` changes than value passed to it needs to change as well.

Comment: That is a bit weak @BroSatse. Your answer has exactly the same flaw. The 5 as the limit of your loop is repeated in the `5 - n`. In both cases easily fixed by introducing a variable. This solution is way cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
1.upto 5 do |n|
  print '  ' * (5-n)
  print '* ' * n
  puts
end
```

Comment: `n += 1` seems to be redundant here

Comment: Or `print '  ' * (5-n); print '* ' * n`

Comment: @user3690932 - Please unaccept this answer and accept Uri's instead. It is much more superior to mine.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

```
def print_two_ways(n, spaces=0)
  arr = Array.new(n) { |i| Array.new(n) { |j| (i >= j) ? '*' : ' ' } }
  print_matrix(arr, spaces)
  puts
  print_matrix(arr.map(&:reverse), spaces)
end

def print_matrix(arr, spaces = 0)
  sep = ' '*(spaces)
  arr.each { |r| puts "#{r.join(sep)}" }
end

print_two_ways(5)
*    
**   
***  
**** 
*****

    *
   **
  ***
 ****
*****

print_two_ways(5,1)
*        
* *      
* * *    
* * * *  
* * * * *

        *
      * *
    * * *
  * * * *
* * * * *
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 5
b = 1
while a>0
 while b<=5
  puts "*"*b
  b = b+1
  a = a-1
end
```

end

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Here, a is 5 and b is 1.
In the first iteration of the outer while loop, a is 1 and the inner while loop is inside the body of the outer while loop. So, the inner while loop will be executed and "*"*1 ( b is 1 ) i.e "*" will be printed and b will become 2 and a will become 4.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Here is simple set variable and use all programs.

# Set vars
n = 4 # Set number of rows
br = "\n" * 2
# Simple loop
puts "Right triangle:#{br}"
for i in 1..n do
  puts "* " * i
end
puts br
=begin
simple loop result:
* 
* * 
* * * 
* * * * 
=end


# Countdown loop
puts "Inverted right triangle:#{br}"
n.downto(0) do
  puts "* " * n
  n -= 1
end
puts br

=begin
countdown loop result:
* * * * 
* * * 
* * 
* 
=end


# Function loop
puts "Inverted pyramid:#{br}"
n = 4 # Reset number of rows
for i in 1..n do
  # Use a func to reduce repetition
  def printer(var, str)
    print "#{str}" * (2 * var - 1)
  end

  printer(i, " ")
  printer(n, "* ")
  print "\n"
  n -= 1
end
puts br
=begin
function loop result:
 * * * * * * * 
   * * * * * 
     * * * 
       * 
=end


# Count up loop
puts "Close pyramid:#{br}"
n = 4 # Set number of rows
i = 1

1.upto(n) do
  #n.times do
  #  print ' '
  #end
  print ' ' * n
  #(2 * i - 1).times do
  #  print '*'
  #end
  print '*' * (2 * i -1)
  print "\n"
  n -= 1
  i += 1
end
print br

=begin
count up loop result:
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
=end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still new to Ruby, but this was my solution. Anything wrong with doing it this way?

```js
def staircase(n)
   
    
    
    sum_tot = n
n.times do 
    sum_tot-= 1
    space =  n - sum_tot
  puts ('#' * space).rjust(n)
  
  end 
end
```

Comment: An answer isn't the place to be asking more questions and having a discussion. Leave follow-up questions in the comments.